# Physx triangle mesh cooking colliding only in one side

Tags: c++, nvidia, physx

I'm on a project for uni about making a simple 3d game with our own engine and using Physx.
Right now i succeeded to create a 3D terrain from a heighmap and cooking it so I could have a collider on it.

You can see on the following image what it looks like, but i have a problem. I can actually go through when on this side of the terrain

[image: This is the terrain that has the collider]

But when im on this side (so under):
[image]

I cant because collisions are good. Now i would like to have it in reverse, i'd like to have collisions on the top of the terrain not from under.

Here is my code :

```
    meshDesc.points.count = static_cast<PxU32>(vertexes.size());
    meshDesc.points.data = vertices;
    meshDesc.points.stride = sizeof(PxVec3);
    meshDesc.triangles.count = static_cast<PxU32>(faces.size())/3;
    meshDesc.triangles.data = indices;
    meshDesc.triangles.stride = 3 * sizeof(PxU32);

    PxTolerancesScale scale1;
    PxCookingParams params(scale1);
    
    // disable mesh cleaning - perform mesh validation on development configurations
    params.meshPreprocessParams |= PxMeshPreprocessingFlag::eDISABLE_CLEAN_MESH;
    // disable edge precompute, edges are set for each triangle, slows contact generation
    params.meshPreprocessParams |= PxMeshPreprocessingFlag::eDISABLE_ACTIVE_EDGES_PRECOMPUTE;
    // lower hierarchy for internal mesh
    params.midphaseDesc.mBVH33Desc.meshCookingHint = PxMeshCookingHint::eCOOKING_PERFORMANCE;

    PhysXManager::get().getPxCooking()->setParams(params);
    PxTriangleMesh* triMesh = NULL;
    triMesh = PhysXManager::get().getPxCooking()->createTriangleMesh(meshDesc, 
    PhysXManager::get().getgPhysx()->getPhysicsInsertionCallback());
    
    
    PxMeshScale geomScale = PxMeshScale((PxVec3(scale)));
    PxTriangleMeshGeometry geom = physx::PxTriangleMeshGeometry(triMesh, geomScale);
    
    body = PhysXManager::get().createTerrain(PxTransform(pos), geom,scene);
```

And in the createTerrain() :

```
PxRigidStatic* PhysXManager::createTerrain(const PxTransform& t, PxTriangleMeshGeometry& geom, int scene) {
    PxShape* shape = PhysXManager::get().getgPhysx()->createShape(geom, *gMaterial, true);
    shape->setName("Terrain");
    PxRigidStatic* body = gPhysics->createRigidStatic(t);
    body->attachShape(*shape);
    addToScene(body, scene);
    return body;
}
```

Can you help me figure out how to do that please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well after doing some tests, i'm just dumb ! Physx is rendered with the other hand referencial, reversing the list before giving it to cooking solved my problem. Closing this.